# OpenGL texture coordinates and the precision of small floats

Tags: opengl, floating-point, precision

I'm using floats to specify texture coordinates, in the range 0-1. OpenGL likes things in this range, and I'm fine specifying coordinates this way, but I'm concerned when I start using larger textures (say up 4096 or 8192 pixels), that I may start losing precision. For example, if I want to specify a coordinate of (1,1) in a 8192x8192px texture, that would map to `1/8192=0.0001220703125`. That seems to evaluate to `0.000122070313` as a float though... I'm concerned that my OpenGL shader won't map that to the same pixel I intended.

I could keep the coordinates as integers in pixels for awhile, but sooner or later I have to convert it (perhaps as late as in the shader itself). Is there a workaround for this, or is this something I should even be concerned about?

---

Multiplying it back out, I get `1.000000004096` which I guess would still be interpreted as `1`? Actually, OpenGL does blending if its not a whole number, doesn't it? Perhaps not with "nearest neighbour", but with "linear" it ought to.

```
1/4096f * 4096 =   1, error = 0
1/8192f * 8192 =   1.000000004096, error =  0.000000004096
1/16384f * 16384 = 1.0000000008192, error = 0.0000000008192
1/32768f * 32768 = 0.9999999991808, error = 0.0000000008192
...
1/1048576f * 1048576 = 0.9999999827968, error = 0.0000000172032
```

(I'm using Visual Studio's debugger to compute the float, and then multiplying it back out with Calculator)

Is the lesson here that the error is negligible for any reasonably sized texture?

Comment: I believe so. I've used some very large textures indeed and the only way to get the precision to break down is to actually zoom into the texture to a point where I'm basically seeing pixels on the screen and even then it still renders okay.

Comment: 2/8192 = 0.000244140625, and the difference between this and 1/8192 is well within the range of single precision, isn't it?

Comment: @MattPhillips: Yes... I figured it would round back to the same pixel, but I wanted to know if it would break down at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That seems to evaluate to 0.000122070313 as a float though... I'm concerned that my OpenGL shader won't map that to the same pixel I intended.

You should not be concerned. Floating point is called *floating* point because the decimal *floats*. You get ~7 digits of precision for your mantissa, more or less regardless of how large or small the float is.

The float isn't stored as 0.000122070313; it's stored as 1.22070313x10^-4. The mantissa is 1.22070313, the exponent is -4. If the exponent were -8 instead, you would have the *same* precision.

Your exponent, with single-precision floats, can go down to + or - ~38. That is, you can have *38 zeros* between the decimal and the first non-zero digit of the mantissa.

So no, you shouldn't be concerned.

The only thing that should concern you would be the precision of the interpolated value and the precision in the texture fetching. But these have nothing to do with the precision of data you store your texture coordinates in.

Comment: I've learned a bit about how floats are stored internally, but I guess it never occurred to me the ramifications of storing the mantissa and exponent separately. That's a nice property! Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Nicol, I'm having the problem you described in the end of your post. I lost precision of uv's interpolated to the pixel shader (I have some huge traingles that the camera is really close up on, exposing uv precision problems when the camera is paning). Do you have any suggestions on overcoming this problem? I thought first of spreading the u-coord over xy and v-coord over zw of a float4 in vs, but I guess the interpolator would screw that up since it interpolates it as 4-components. Is there a way to increase precision? I would prefer not to tesselate that huge triangles just because of this.